# Can you please show me any example related to this AND Condition in SharePoint Calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have taken a SharePoint list based on budget. I wanted to take a Calculated column named Budget Scarcity based on Budget Amount and Used Amount. I wanted to Use AND Condition, but was getting errors when I used that formula.

Formula:

`=AND(10$<[Budget Amount],[Budget Amount]<10000$),"Yes","No")`

`=AND(1<[Col1], [Col1]<100)`

[image]

Thank you so much regards.

Comment: What is Col1 referring to in your formula? Is that supposed to be Used Amount?

Comment: Hi @Chandrika, is my solution given below working for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
=IF(AND(AND(10<[Budget Amount],[Budget Amount]<10000),AND(1<Col1,Col1<100)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will show you an example how to use the AND function in SharePoint calculated columns below.

I have created a new SharePoint list and then created a `Budget Amount` column with data type of Number. Here are the column settings:

[image]

Then I have created a new calculated column using below formula:

```
=IF(AND([Budget Amount] > 500, [Budget Amount] < 15000), "Yes", "No")
```

This will result to "Yes" if Budget Amount is greater than 500 AND less than 15000.

**Output**:

[image]

---

Syntax of AND function is like:

```
AND(condition1,condition2,condition3,...)
```

You can add up to 30 conditions inside single `AND()` function.

**Official Documentation**: [AND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-78956048-53c7-484a-ab0b-6e70d7f03400)